# SCSS/JS changes don't get noticed while reloading with browserSync using Gulp 4

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, browser-sync

When I make changes to any file that is being watched by Gulp, the browser doesn't reload with the `scss/js` changes, only reads and updates the changes made to the `index.html`.

Also the `main.css` that is supposed to be built with every change I make to `scss` files don't get updated. The reload action does get triggered by changes in `scss` files but they don't get applied.

I'm using Gulp v4.0.2 as my task runner.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/reactuser13/bc8a1afacd7b902287e576c35ee01f26) the link to my `gulpfile.js`

I'm expecting to see `scss/js` changes on reload action.

Answer (score 0):

Since v4 gulp has a different [syntax](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks).
BrowserSync also [updated](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp) and now you have to call `.create()` method

```js
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```

But anyway, try to follow this guide [minimal-browsersync-setup-with-gulp4.md](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/minimal-browsersync-setup-with-gulp4.md), hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

could this simply be a caching problem? did you check in the `dist/main.css` if the changes appear?